# Can you specify generics type on map value?

Tags: java, generics

In Java (5+) you can do:

```
TreeMap<String, List> map = someObject.getMap();
```

But can specify the generic type within the `List`?  A la:

```
TreeMap<String, List<String>> map = someObject.getMap();
```

??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You sure can.  Works great.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.  Do you have a compiler error in your code you want help fixing?

Answer (score 2):

Yes,why not? But keep in mind that the type gets erased in the compiled code, so isn't runtime available. That can be a problem if you access it with reflection.

Answer (score 2):

You can nest generic types to arbitrary number of levels. E.g :

```
 TreeMap<String, List<Map<String, String>>>
```